# C# equivalent of Java awaitility

Tags: c#, selenium, async-await, wait, webdriverwait

I would like to replicate something that I have in Java to C#.

I'm NOT looking for, or anything that will involve the driver:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

I'm using the http://www.awaitility.org/.

Here is the code:

```
public static void waitForElement(WebElement element) {

    with()
            .pollDelay(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .and()
            .pollInterval(200, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .await()
            .ignoreExceptions()
            .until(() -> element.isDisplayed());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like

```cs
public static async Task WaitForElementAsync(WebElement element)
{
    await With(100, 200, true, () => element.isDisplayed());
}

private static async Task With(
    int pollDeley,
    int pollIntervall,
    bool ignoreException,
    Func<bool> until)
{
    await Task.Delay(pollDeley);

    var loop = true;

    while (loop)
    {
        try
        {
            loop = !until();
            if (!loop) break;
            await Task.Delay(pollIntervall);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!ignoreException) throw;
        }
    }
}
```

but there might be a better solution if `WebElement` has an event like `IsDisplayedChanged`.

Also with this solution you introduce a async call line to your project (which in a web context can be beneficial), to avoid this you can replace the `await Task.Delay(...)` with `Thread.Sleep(...)`.

Another solution would be to use a timer for the polling

```cs
private static async Task With(
    int pollDeley,
    int pollIntervall,
    bool ignoreException,
    Func<bool> until)
{
    await Task.Delay(pollDeley);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    using (var timer = new Timer(pollIntervall))
    {
        void Poll(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (until())
                {
                    if (tcs.TrySetResult(true))
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!ignoreException)
                {
                    if (tcs.TrySetException(ex))
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        timer.Elapsed += Poll;

        timer.Start();

        await tcs.Task;

        timer.Elapsed -= Poll;
    }
}
```